# Adding tag slug to post permalink

Tags: permalinks, tags

I'm trying to create a permalink structure for regular posts that looks something like this:    `/category-name/tag-name/post-name`

I've been using an AI friend that insists I simply use custom permalinks with the value set to `/%category%/%tag%/%postname%/`

I don't know where it's getting this information from but we all know this won't work. Does anyone know how I can achieve this programmatically?

**Example of what final product should look like:**

`website.com/stores/hairdressers/post-about-a-hair-dresser`

Comment: Can you check in permalink structure and use custom structure ?

Comment: Will you please summarize your category structure, and provide a sample URL, with explanation on what each segment in the URL is? `%tag%` is not a native tag for permalinks, so that definitely won't work without customization.

Comment: Hi @Caleb, I've updated the question above to include an example. I know that it looks like I should be using subcategories instead of tags, however this is a very large website, very big client, and they want to use tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new tag (e.g. `%tag%`) that you can use in post links.
One possibility is to use the [`add_rewrite_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/) function.

Then use the [`post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/) filter to replace the `%tag%` in the link with the appropriate value.

Finally, change the post link structure in the settings.

> Settings -> Permalinks -> Custom Structure:
> `/%category%/%tag%/%postname%/`

Optionally, using [`available_permalink_structure_tags`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/available_permalink_structure_tags/) filter, you can add a new tag to the list of available tags, which is visible on the settings page.

```
add_action( 'init', 'se416974_tag_in_permalink' );

function se416974_tag_in_permalink()
{
    add_rewrite_tag( '%tag%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_filter( 'post_link',  'se416974_post_link', 20, 2 );
}

function se416974_post_link( $link, $post )
{
    if ( FALSE === stripos($link, '%tag%') )
        return $link;
    $tags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
    if ( !is_array($tags) || 0 == count($tags) )
        return str_replace( '%tag%', 'no-tag', $link );

    $first_tag = current( $tags );
    $new_link = str_replace( '%tag%', $first_tag->slug, $link );
    return $new_link;
}

function se416974_available_tags( $available_tags )
{
    $available_tags['tag'] = '%s (One of tags assigned to post)';
    return $available_tags;
}
```

Comment: Hi nmr, thank you for your reply. So I've tried the above and it appears to generate the correct URL, and it may or may not be a seperate issue, however when traveling to the newly generated URL I get a 400 Bad Request error and the url changes to replace the tag with %tag%, eg: /category-name/%tag%/post-name

I've tried resaving the permalink structure but this hasn't helped. Do you know what is happening here? Is this a seperate issue?

Comment: I checked the code on a clean install of the latest WP and it worked fine. 
It's possible you have some custom rewrite rules causing this. 
Try disabling one plugin at a time or change the theme and check if the links work.

Comment: You could also check what rewrite rules you have by displaying properties of `global $wp_rewrites` somewhere on the page:  `$wp_rewrite->permalink_structure`, `$wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs`, `$wp_rewrite->extra_rules_top`, `$wp_rewrite->extra_rules`.